# Jquery, timeinterval and if statements

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, intervals

Im doing some kind of `jQuery` game and got stuck. I need help with two things.

1. I have a playing board with a player. The player is moving with the help of the arrows on the keyboard. My problem is that the player goes outside of the playing board, I don't want this. What should i do to make it not be able to go outside of the box.
2. I have made some kind of "food" that spawns at a random X location every time i refresh. But i want it to spawn at a random location every one second for example, and that there therefore can be more than one "food" on the board.

Here is what I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode ==39 && $("#spelare").css("left") < '880px')  
      $("#spelare").animate({left: '+=20px'}, 0);
    else if (e.keyCode ==37 && $("#spelare").css("left") > '0px') 
      $("#spelare").animate({left: '-=20px'}, 0);
  });

  $('.food').each(function() {
    var spelplanWidth = $('#spelplan').width();//Screen width
    var foodPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * spelplanWidth));

    $(this).css('left', foodPosX);
    setInterval(function() {
      var spelplanWidth = $('#spelplan').width();//Screen width
      var foodPosX = Math.floor((Math.random()*spelplanWidth));
     
      $(this).css('left', foodPosX);
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color:black;
}

#spelplan{
  width: 50%;
  height:65vh;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:25%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
#spelare{
  width:15%;
  height: 12vh;
  position: relative;
  top:53.4vh;
  background-color:red;
}

.food{
  width:5%;
  height:5vh;
  position:relative;
  background-color:blue;
}

p {
  position:relative;
  font-family: 'Electrolize', sans-serif;
}

#poäng{
  color:white;
  bottom:17vh;
  right:45%;
}

#liv{
  color:white;
  bottom:18vh;
  right:46.5%;
}

.fa-heart{
  color:red;
  bottom:21.5vh;
  right:43.5%;
  position:relative;
}

#info{
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Electrolize', sans-serif;
  margin-top:68vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 style="color:white">JQUERY SPEL</h2>
<div id="spelplan">
  <div id="spelare"> </div>
  <div class="food"> </div>
  <p id="poäng"> Poäng:   </p>
  <p id="liv"> Liv: </p>
  <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Yikes, you gotta work on you code formatting, see the edit I have done to see how your code should be formatted.

Comment: I would avoid using special characters in css selectors like: `#poäng`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To keep the player from moving too far, you need to add a condition to your if statement before moving each direction to make sure it won't exceed your game board

2) Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.  `setTimeout` calls the function once after a set period.  `setInterval` repeats forever until told to stop by `clearInterval()`.  If that is needed you, must assign the `setInterval` function to a variable you can access later.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).keydown(function(e){ 
        if (e.keyCode ==39 && $("#spelare").css("left") < 800) //or whatever your right most position is
            $("#spelare").animate({left: '+=20px'}, 0);
        else if (e.keyCode ==37 && $("#spelare").css("left") > 100) 
            $("#spelare").animate({left: '-=20px'}, 0);
    });

  setInterval(spawnFood,1000);
});

function spawnFood(){
   var spelplanWidth = $('#spelplan').width();
   var foodPosX = Math.floor((Math.random()*spelplanWidth));
   var element = "<div class='food'></div>"
   $(element).css('left',foodPosX);
   $("#spelplan").append(element);
}
```

Comment: Problem number 1. is solved. Thank you for that. But i still dont really understand how i should get the "food" to spawn automatically. I have changed it to setinterval, but does not work.

Comment: What is `foodPosX`?  A random number I assume? And is there a reason you're using the variable `food` in the .each() function instead of `this`?  See my edit and try that. Assuming your random value is setup correctly.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have `var spelplanWidth = $('#spelplan').width()//Screen width` and   `var foodPosX = Math.floor((Math.random()*spelplanWidth))` `foodPosX` is meant to be a random location on X. Pretty sure it works as it changes location every time i refresh the site, but does not do it automatically otherwise. Changed to `this` but it did not seem to work either :/

Comment: You need to put your random generator in the setInterval function.  Otherwise it will just use the same X position every time.

Comment: Hmm, I edited my original post, can you take a look at it and maybe find whats wrong. thanks.

Comment: You only have one div with the class "food" in your markup.  So there will only ever be one food item changing x position every second.

Comment: I changed your `.each()` function and added a new function to spawn a food element.  That will insert a new food element every second at a random location forever.

Comment: So now it kinda works. It is spawning a new object every second, but on the wrong axis, it is spawning on the same X axis, while I want it to spawn on the same Y axis.  And the random stopped working, it spawns one after another on the X axis.

Comment: Do you know what i can do to make them spawn randomly on the specific Y? instead of X, thanks

Comment: Use the height instead of the width for your math calculations.  If you have other questions you'll need to open a new question, this one has already gotten a little long.  and if I helped you please consider up voting and or marking as the answer.